# Can react-google-maps use Image Map Types?

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, react-google-maps

i'm tring to reproduce the example show in: 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/maptype-image

with react-google-maps.
it doesn't seem to have the same class google.maps.ImageMapType.
Did u know if there's a class that can help me or if someone already did this, link me the example?

```
  <GoogleMap
className="maps"
defaultZoom={17}
defaultCenter={{ lat: 46.215951, lng: 12.306994 }}
defaultMapTypeId="moon"
defaultExtraMapTypes={[{id:"moon", mapType:{
      getTileUrl: function(coord, zoom) {
          return "mw1.google.com/mw-planetary/lunar/lunarmaps_v1/clem_bw/1/1/0.jpg";
      },
      maxZoom: 9,
      minZoom: 0,
      radius: 1738000,
      name: 'Moon'
    }}]}
defaultOptions={{
 // these following 7 options turn certain controls off see link below
  streetViewControl: false,
  scaleControl: false,
  mapTypeControl: false,
  panControl: false,
  zoomControl: false,
  rotateControl: false,
  fullscreenControl: false
}}

disableDefaultUI>
```

i try to do something like that

Comment: Could you share the code you tried and error message?

Comment: i link my code. It doesnt give any error just an empty map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the trick.
I create the const ImageMapType like the example show and exported it.

in my map component i use these properties:

```
defaultOptions={{
              maxZoom: 18,
              mapTypeControlOptions: {
                mapTypeIds: ['moon','satellite']
              }
          }}
          mapTypeId={google ? 'moon' : 'satellite'}
          defaultExtraMapTypes={[
              ['moon', mapStyles ]
          ]}
```

to link it the map.
defaultExtraMapTypes replace the map.set in the google api.